# difficulty setting loop based on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my controller:

```
def sedomain 
@domain = params[:domain]
@virksomhed = Virksomhed.find(:all)
end
```

Virksomhed has_one Domain and Domain belongs_to Virksomhed.

That I am trying to achieve is looping through all rows in the domain table based on the params.

Here is a example for the dk domain page. It works fine.

```
<% @virksomhed.each do |virk| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= virk.navn %></td>
        <td><%= virk.domain.dk %> kr.</td>
        <td><%= virk.domain.dkf %></td>
        <td><%= virk.domain.dko %></td>

    </tr>
     <% end %>
```

But then I want to make it dynamic:

```
<% @virksomhed.each do |virk| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= virk.navn %></td>
        <td><%= virk.domain.@domain %> kr.</td>
        <td><%= virk.domain.@domain %></td>
        <td><%= virk.domain.@domain %></td>

    </tr>
     <% end %>
```

But I get a syntax error. I also think it is a bad solution because of users can access other columns in the Domain table via the params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dereference variables like this. What you mean to do is use `send`:

```
<td><%= virk.domain.send(@domain) %> kr.</td>
```

You will want to ensure that this user parameter conforms to a list of "known good" ones. There's two ways you might go about doing this, either pre-filtering and throwing an error if it's not valid, or having a method that eats the call quietly if it doesn't conform.

For instance:

```
@domain =
  case(params[:domain])
  when 'dk', 'dku', '...'
    params[:domain]
  else
    raise "Hey, what are you doing?"
  end
```

Comment: Instead of creating a whitelist is it possiable to create a blacklist. Because my whitelist would be very long which is not very pretty.

Comment: Secure is more important than pretty. If you're concerned about a long list in your controller code, put it in a config file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

@tadman's answer is good, but i'd like to add my two cents. As @Emily said, you can store your whitelisted domains as a set in a Constant :

```
require 'set'
DOMAINS = Set.new( %W{dk dkf dko} )
```

As i understand it, your `params[:domain]` can either be an array or a string. to check if the domain is whitelisted, you can then do:

```
# ...
@domains= check_domains( params[:domain] )
# ...

def check_domains( dom )
  case dom
    when Array
      dom if dom.to_set.subset?( DOMAINS )
    else
      [dom] if DOMAINS.include?( dom )
  end
  dom ||= []
end
```

then in your view (or maybe as some helper / partial):

```
<% if @domains.any? %>
  <% @domains.each do |domain| %>
    <td><%= virk.domain.send(domain) %> kr.</td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```